# How can I save HTML template code in a cell as-is?

Tags: html, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have an HTML email template that I would like to save in a cell in google sheet.

The code looks like this example: [Email HTML code example](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_templates_cafe)

Issue: problem is that google sheet is breaking the HTML code. After pasting the complete email template HTML code in a cell, when I copy it back, anywhere I have `" "` becomes `"" ""`. Not sure where else code is breaking. So far, this is the only issue I have noticed.

Like this:

`<p class="w3-text-grey">`

becomes this

`<p class=""w3-text-grey"">`

or another example is...

this:
 `<a href="#" class="w3-button w3-block w3-black">HOME</a>`

becomes this

`<a href=""#"" class=""w3-button w3-block w3-black"">HOME</a>`

It looks the like cell is formatting the value into something.
Any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

one way would be to not store the whole HTML code in one cell, but a range/column and then copy/paste back the range of cells

if you still need it to be stored in one cell then the other way around would be not to copy the actual cell but fx bar:

[image: 0]

Comment: Another way is to put the cell in edit mode by double clicking on it or by pressing F2, then select all and copy.